# Problems with a linsay f-10hd cosmos locked

Tags: adb, sim-unlocking

so I have this tablet linsay f-10hd 
Specs
10.1 "  0S: 4.04 Google Android CPU: 1.5 Ghz CORTEX A-8 1 GB RAM 4 GB Hard Drive Internal Memory Web CameraBuilt in 3-D acceleration, 3-D Effect 2160 P HD Wi-Fi Supported: WIRELESS 802.11 B/G HDMI mini HDMI Support 3 D Vision 2160 P HD Video player: Mp4, Avi you can watch your favorite Movies! USB port to Portable External Hard drive up to 3 TB USB port for 3G use

and I got locked out, forgot my email and password and I have been trying to unlocked it
by doing a hard reset(vol+ and power)which takes me to the android logo

so I try to use adb

adb shell
cd /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases
sqlite3 settings.db
update system set value=0 where name='lock_pattern_autolock';
update system set value=0 where name='lockscreen.lockedoutpermanently';
.quit
reboot

adb shell 
rm /data/system/gesture.key
reboot
so i start with

adb devices
and get    20080411        recovery

but nothing I get and error.
what can i do

Answer (score 0):

You can use the android recovery by holding the power on and the +volumn buttons at same time releasing the power button as soon as the icon apears on the sceen but still hoding down the +volumn button.Then when the andoid appears press the power button and volumn+ button again and release the volumn+ button first, the recovery program should start up and then you can reset the tablet